# Error playing embedded youtube video iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, youtube, embed

I embedded a YouTube Video into my app with following code.

```
NSString *embedCode = @"<iframe width=\"322\" height=\"180\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XKTkQ9oNgyE\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
[[self webView] loadHTMLString:embedCode baseURL:nil];
```

Everything works as it should in the simulator (The video plays in fullscreen).

On my device it shows the thumbnail but when I press play it says
"An error occurred. Please try again later."

[image: Thumbnail]

[image: Error]

Im using Xcode 7 and iOS 9.

Answer (score 0):

I  think this might be fixed now. A few days ago, I had the same error unless I used the App Transport Security "free pass".

Now, embedded YouTube videos seem to work fully in iOS 9 without any security exceptions.

Comment: I don't think it was an iOS fix; it started working more recently! I think Google upgraded their servers to comply with the full ATS requirements.

Comment: I have the same issue..it's working on iOS 9 but not in iOS 8.